# How can I convert a time shown as a character into time value with R?

Tags: r, date, time, lubridate, chron

I have a dataset calles marathon and I have tried to use lubridate and churn to convert the characters of marathon$Official.Time into time value in order to work on them. I would like the times to be shown in minutes (meaning that 2 hours are shown as 120 minutes).

```
data.frame':    5616 obs. of  11 variables:
$ Overall.Position : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
$ Gender.Position  : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
$ Category.Position: int  1 1 2 2 3 4 3 4 5 5 ...
$ Category         : chr  "MMS" "MMI" "MMI" "MMS" ...
$ Race.No          : int  21080 14 2 21077 18 21 21078 21090 21084 12 ...
$ Country          : chr  "Kenya" "Kenya" "Ethiopia" "Kenya" ...
$ Official.Time    : chr  "2:12:12" "2:12:14" "2:12:20" "2:12:29" ...
```

I tried with:

```
  library(lubridate)
  times(marathon$Official.Time)
```

Or

```
  library(chron)
  chron(times=marathon$Official.Time)
  as.difftime(marathon$Official.Time, units = "mins")
```

But I only get NA

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there with `difftime` (which requires two times and gives you the difference). Instead, use `as.difftime` (which requires one "difference" - ie marathon time) and specify the `format` as hours:minutes:seconds.

```
> as.difftime("2:12:12", format="%H:%M:%S", units="mins")
Time difference of 132.2 mins
> as.numeric(as.difftime("2:12:12", format="%H:%M:%S", units="mins"))
[1] 132.2
```

No extra packages needed.

Comment: I think that the seconds are not represented correctly. Those are decimal fractions of a minute.

Comment: @RHertel I don't quite understand what you mean. If you want to know how many minutes '12 minutes and 30 seconds' is, it should be '12.5', not '12.3'. If you wish to know the time in minutes, then the seconds are always expressed as a decimal fraction.

Comment: Aye, I'll reply here as well. You're also making an assumption the OP hasn't verified.

Comment: The times are hours, minutes, seconds. So in the case 2:12:12 we should have 132 minutes and 12 seconds instead of 132.2 minutes, I think.

Comment: Why are you trying to divine what the OP hasn't even stated as a requirement @RHertel?

Comment: The OP says they want the time in minutes and their attempts at a solution make it clear they are after a number. 132.2 minutes *is* 2:12:12. If they were after the string "132 minutes and 12 seconds", I think their attempts at a solution would look somewhat different.

Comment: They haven't said they want a string.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I'm not trying to divine anything, just pointing out a possible problem. If you think that a time like "147.95 minutes" makes sense, then please, go ahead. Usually seconds are not converted into decimal fractions of minutes though.

Comment: I beg to differ. When working with times (for comparisons, etc), they are *always* converted to numbers. A time of "147.95 minutes" absolutely makes sense. The only reason to convert back to a string is to present the result in a friendly way, in which case "2:12:12" would be fine. In any case, the OP says they want to "convert the characters of marathon$Official.time into time value in order to work on them". This implies some sort of analysis, for which the times **must** be numbers.

Comment: @RHertel you aren't the OP. You're making an assumption for the OP and being pretty persistent about it. I'm just stating you might not be as correct as you think you are.

Comment: Alright, the solutions are quite possibly correct as they are. Having said this I would appreciate a less confrontational reaction to my comments, which aimed at a possible improvement.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: @mathemetical.coffee's solution is ++gd better than these.

---

Pretty straightforward to kick it out manually:

```
library(stringi)
library(purrr)

df <- data.frame(Official.Time=c("2:12:12","2:12:14","2:12:20","2:12:29"),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

map(df$Official.Time, function(x) {
  stri_split_fixed(x, ":")[[1]] %>%
    as.numeric() %>%
    `*`(c(60, 1, 1/60)) %>%
    sum()
}) -> df$minutes

df
##   Official.Time  minutes
## 1       2:12:12    132.2
## 2       2:12:14 132.2333
## 3       2:12:20 132.3333
## 4       2:12:29 132.4833
```

You can also do it with just base R operations and w/o "piping":

```
df$minutes <- sapply(df$Official.Time, function(x) {

 x <- strsplit(x, ":", TRUE)[[1]]
 x <- as.numeric(x)
 x <- x * (c(60, 1, 1/60))

 sum(x)

}, USE.NAMES=FALSE)
```

If "stuck" with base R then I'd prbly actually do:

```
vapply(df$Official.Time, function(x) {

 x <- strsplit(x, ":", TRUE)[[1]]
 x <- as.numeric(x)
 x <- x * (c(60, 1, 1/60))

 sum(x)

}, double(1), USE.NAMES=FALSE)
```

to ensure type safety.

But, `chron` can also be used:

```
library(chron)

60 * 24 * as.numeric(times(df$Official.Time))
```

NOTE that `lubridate` has no `times()` function.